# retornar valores de metódos assincronos javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá estou com um problema aqui, eu preciso usar o modulo do node request, duas vezes. uma pra pegar o link de uma página e o outro pra pegar o conteúdo de uma postagem.

desta forma, estou com o seguinte problema:

```
request('https://www.pensarcontemporaneo.com/, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    // na página inicial ele vai pegar o link de uma postagem recente...
    const href = $('.td_block_inner').find('.td-module-thumb').children().first().attr('href');

    // aqui ele vai entrar neste link pra pegar o conteúdo da postagem
    request(href, function (error2, response2, body2) {
      const $2 = cheerio.load(body);
      // preste atenção, eu preciso que essa variavel vá para dentro da array article
      var content = $2('.td-ss-main-content').html();
      console.log(content); // aparece o conteúdo
    });

    var article = {
      // só que aqui ele chega vazio
      content: content,
      link: href,
      thumb: $('.td_block_inner').find('img').first().attr('src'),
      title: $('.td_block_inner').find('.entry-title').children().first().text(),
    }
  }
});
```

Eu venho do php por isso não tenho muita experiência com javascript, muito menos com node, to muito desorientado.

Comment: A declaração da variável `article` **deve** estar dentro do *callback* da segunda requisição. Como o `request` é assíncrono, ele vai executar o restante do código (`var article = { ... }`) antes de mesmo da requisição terminar e você ter o valor de `content`. Outra coisa, a variável `content` (na segunda requisições) ela é local e não será visível fora dessa função.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é utilizar [**Promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) ou https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request

Comment: Valdeir obrigado, coloquei o article dentro do segundo request, como eu não pensei nisso antes, valeu bro ;)